# How to call function D only after function A, B and C are done

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

Hi guys I'd like to know if its possible to call function "confirm" only IF functions checkV, checkV1, checkV2 are done and the form is completly filled in.

HTML & javascript

http://pastebin.com/xY1MBhv5

```js
function checkV() {
  var check = document.getElementById("voornaam").value;

  if (isNaN(check) || check.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("In de naamvelden geen cijfers invoeren s.v.p.");
  }

};

function checkV1() {
  var check1 = document.getElementById("achternaam").value;

  if (isNaN(check1) || check1.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("In de naamvelden geen cijfers invoeren s.v.p.");
  }
};

function checkV2() {
  var check2 = document.getElementById("toneelspeler").value;

  if (isNaN(check2) || check2.length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("In de naamvelden geen cijfers invoeren s.v.p.");
  }
};


function confirm() {
  var voorNaam = document.getElementById("voornaam").value;
  var toneelNaam = document.getElementById("toneelspeler").value;
  var achterNaam = document.getElementById("achternaam").value;

  alert("Beste " + voorNaam + " " + achterNaam + ", ontzettend bedankt voor je wens, we zullen ervoor zorgen dat            " + toneelNaam + " je wens zal ontvangen!");

};

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {

    checkV()
    checkV1()
    checkV2()
    confirm()
  };
};
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="home.html">
      <img src="logo.png" id="home" alt="Logo van Het Imperium Theater">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank">
      <img src="facebook.png" id="facebook" alt="facebook" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="blank">
      <img src="twitter.png" id="twitter" alt="twitter" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Agenda.html">Agenda</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Het Theater.html">Het Theater</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Ontdek Leiden.html">Ontdek Leiden</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<div id="wrapper">

  <form id="form" name="form">
    <h1>Verstuur een wens.</h1>
    <div id="forms">
      <label for="voornaam">Voornaam:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="voornaam" placeholder="uw voornaam" name="fname" required>
      </label>
      <label for="achternaam">Achternaam:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="achternaam" placeholder="uw achternaam" name="fname" required>
      </label>
      <label for="toneelspeler">Naam toneelspeler:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="toneelspeler" placeholder="naam van de toneelspeler" name="fname" required>
      </label>
      <label for="boodschap">Uw wens:
        <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="name" placeholder="Type hier uw wens" required></textarea>
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">

  </form>

</div>

<footer>
  <a href="home.html">
    <p>Theater Imperium</p>
  </a>
  <p>Oude Vest 33e</p>
  <p>2312 XR Leiden</p>
  <p>071 5141035</p>
  <p>&copy; Arpiar Melikjan</p>

</footer>
```

Comment: create variables for if checkV checkV1 and checkV2 are done. Default value false, at the end of those 3 functions, set their corresponding variable true. At the start of "confirm" say `if(checkVdone && checkV2done && checkV3done){[everything]}`.I don't know much about validation, but you could check every field for a value besides the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link provided, if everything goes fine, `checkV(), checkV1()` and `checkV2()` will return `true`, otherwise `undefined`. You can do something like this:

```
if(checkV() && checkV1() && checkV2())
    //Do submit
```

**EDIT:**

If you want more control over your control flow (which might be helpful in debugging), you might do something like this:

```
if(checkV()) {
    if(checkV1()) {
        if(checkV2()) {
            //Do submit
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can associate `else` blocks, and can take action according to the method which failed to validate your input.

Comment: That would be very hard to debug and maintain if you needed to know _which_ function returned false.  Nesting functions looks cool, but it aint.

Comment: I have another question, when a number is filled in, i get an alert which says  you cant fill in number, this is correct. But for example when I fill in "hey12", the function validates it as correct. So when a number is filled in, in combination with a character the valiadation is correct while it shouldnt be.

Comment: For that, you can test it against a regular expression, like this: `if( /^([^0-9]*)$/.test('hey12') ) {}`